# Why does read -a fail in zsh

Tags: arrays, zsh

If I type:

```
echo "1 the
dquote> 2 quick
dquote> 3 brown" | while read -a D; do echo "${D[1]}--${D[0]}"; done
```

in bash it says:

```
the--1
quick--2
brown--3
```

but in zsh it says:

```
zsh: bad option: -a
```

Why? And what should I do instead?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In both shells `read` is a builtin. It shares the same purpose, but the implementation and options differ.

In order to read in an array in `zsh`, `read` requires the option `-A` (instead of `-a`):

```sh
echo "1 the
2 quick   
3 brown" | while read -A D; do echo $D[2]--$D[1]; done
```

---

**Note:** There are many more differences between `zsh` and `bash`:

- In `zsh` arrays are numbered from one by default, in `bash` they start from zero.
- `echo $ARRAY` prints outputs all elements in `zsh` but only the first element in `bash`
- To print the third element of an array in `sh` you can use `echo $ARRAY[3]`. In `bash` braces are needed to delimit the subscript, also the subscript for the third element is `2`: `echo ${ARRAY[2]}`.
- In `zsh` you usually do not need to quote parameter expansions in order to handle values with white spaces correctly. For example

  ```sh
  FILENAME="no such file"
  cat $FILENAME
  ```

  will print only one error message in `zsh`:

  ```sh
  cat: 'no such file': No such file or directory
  ```

  but three error messages in `bash`:

  ```sh
  cat: no: No such file or directory
  cat: such: No such file or directory
  cat: file: No such file or directory
  ```
- In `zsh` the builtin `echo` evaluates escape codes by default. In `bash` you need to pass the `-e` argument for that.

  ```sh
  echo 'foo\tbar'
  ```

  `zsh`:

  ```sh
  foo     bar
  ```

  `bash`:

  ```sh
  foo\tbar
  ```
- …

Generally, it is important to keep in mind that, while `zsh` and `bash` are similar, they are far from being the same.

Comment: Hmm. It doesn't seem to use -a for anything else. Seems like a strangely pointless incompatibility.

Comment: Neither shell aims to be compatible with the other shell. They both try to be compliant with POSIX, but neither  `-a` nor `-A` are options for the POSIX variant of `read`. I would guess that `zsh` uses `-A` to be consistent with its `set` builtin, which also uses `-A` to set an array. BTW: it is the other way around; `bash` (2.0 in 1996) did not follow `zsh`'s example (2.5 in 1994) in using `-A`, which is strange, as it does not use `-A` for anything else. ;)

Comment: I think zsh does try to be compatible with bash when nothing speaks against it. zsh may have been first but bash is thousands of times more popular. zsh isn't using -a for anything else, so I think it should just do the pragmatic thing. 1996 was 20 years ago.

Comment: Like I wrote:`bash` and `zsh` are - very - different, expecting otherwise, will only lead problems. Changing this one option will not change that. And really, why should `zsh` break an established behavior just to be more like `bash`? If you want bash constructs, use `bash`. If you want portable code, use POSIX compliant constructs. If you want to take advantage of the features `zsh`, you will need to use zsh constructs, many of which will be more or less different from those in `bash`.